# compiling src.jar and .jar using pom

Tags: java, maven

I am building my jar abc.jar. At the same time I am also building the abc-sources.jar.
I am having a project xyz which is dependent on abc.jar. So I am adding abc.jar in the classpath. But when I am trying to debug and see the source code of abc.jar through reference libraries of xyz project I always get source not attached so I have to also include abc-sources.jar file in the classpath of xyz in order to debug through the source of abc.

I guess is there something wrong with my eclipse workspace or is there another way of compiling abc.jar to get the source code or is it that my eclipse needs another plugin?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use m2e or m2eclipse, right-click the project and select `Maven > Download Artifact Sources`

Or activate it permanently by selecting `Window > Preferences > Maven > Download Artifact Sources` from the Menu Bar

---

If you use the maven-eclipse-plugin, do it like this:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```